# Does participation in the Careers beta or the Private Beta increase your reputation?

Tags: support, jobs, beta-phase, private-beta

Is there some extra reputation boost for active participation in the betas?

It's not mentioned anywhere in the FAQ and I was wondering if involvement there showered you in any extra benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there was anything given in terms of reputation from the beta; however, any reputation earned from questions and answers during the beta period did carry over. Not sure if that would count as being given reputation per se, but you could argue that it did make it a bit easier to earn some reputation since questions would stay on the homepage longer at that time.

Comment: ohk .. :-) thanx for the response ..

Answer (score 4):

I highly doubt it. Even for participation in the Stack Overflow *site* beta all you got was a lousy badge (yeah, that's envy. I don't have it.)

Comment: hmm .. I see .. Thanx for the response ..

Comment: Shiny badge, shiny badge, shiny badge :)

Comment: Shiny ? It wasn't even as shiny as as the formerly `woot` badge.

Answer (score 3):

No.